# jsp - display tomcat configuration on jsp page

Tags: apache, jsp, file-upload, tomcat7

How can I display the value of **maxPostSize** from **the server.xml** of an apache tomcat 7 on my jsp page? By the way is there any solution to display the whole configuration?

---

I need to know if the multipart request overwrites the tomcat configuration in server.xml. That doesn't seem alright, but I think that's the truth.

java

```
MultipartRequest multi = new MultipartRequest(request, path, 5*1024*1024);
```

server.xml

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" maxPostSize="1048576" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jep, I found out that the multipart request overrides the tomcat configuration. So I can easily set the max upload file size in the constructor of the multipart request.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you use a easy js xml plugin to display the whole xml.

http://www.levmuchnik.net/Content/ProgrammingTips/WEB/XMLDisplay/DisplayXMLFileWithJavascript.html#Usage